# Why rsAccessDenied error on SSRS when using Chrome but not in IE

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, permissions, active-directory, ssrs-2008

I am trying to identify reason why SSRS service URL **throws an exception when using Chrome while not with IE**.

I tried running both of them with Administrative account.

http://xyz-shantanug/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

> User 'Domain\userName' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.

http://xyz-shantanug/ReportServer

> The permissions granted to user 'Domain\userName' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help

With Administrative account, both URL works on IE but not on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is not a supported browser for use with Reporting Services 2008, and will not support NTLM or Kerberos authentication:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511%28v=sql.100%29.aspx